# PostgreSQL psql command line tool and SET CONSTRAINTS DEFERRED

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am using PostgreSQL 9.1.5 and the **psql** to run a scipt containing a series of **INSERT** statements in various tables:

```
psql -U usernamefoo databasenamefoo -f dml_script.sql
```

The table constraints have been created with the **DEFERRABLE** option and the script itself (file dml_script.sql above) issues the following before an offending **INSERT**:

```
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;                  
INSERT INTO KM_TRANSACTION_GROUPS ..
```

I've checked that the specific constraint on the table in question has been created with the **DEFRRABLE** option:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY KM_TRANSACTION_GROUPS ADD CONSTRAINT TRGR_TRGR_FK FOREIGN KEY (TRGR_PARENT_ID) REFERENCES KM_TRANSACTION_GROUPS(TRGR_ID) DEFERRABLE;
```

Yet, running the DML script fails:

```
psql:./schema-dml-test.sql:8: ERROR:  insert or update on table "km_transaction_groups" violates foreign key constraint "trgr_trgr_fk"
DETAIL:  Key (trgr_parent_id)=(2) is not present in table "km_transaction_groups".
```

My guess is that psql treats each **INSERT** line in the dml_script.sql as a separate transaction. If that's the reason, is there a way to group INSERT statements in the dml_script.sql file into one longer transaction (or perhaps treat the whole file as one single transaction) so that at its end (when the scope of the **SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;** terminates), no constraints are violated?

Otherwise some other method (other then changing the order of the INSERT statements which I have reasons I don't want to) to allow me to load the table with a series of **INSERT** statements so that constraints can be temporarily deactivated ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-1` option to [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html) causes it to wrap a file specified by `-f` in a `BEGIN`..`COMMIT` block, making it a transaction.

Otherwise, add the `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` commands to your script so that it becomes a single transaction.

Comment: Yup - by default interactive `psql` sessions are "every line is a transaction": You need explicit `BEGIN`/`ROLLBACK`/`COMMIT` statements if you want a multi-statement transaction...

Comment: See the documentation: **[Transactions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-transactions.html)**

Comment: You can also turn off that dreaded autocommit mode using: `\set AUTOCOMMIT off` (I have that in my psqlrc file)